# Where clause with three options

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016 Dev and I have a `WHERE` clause with 3 options.

I solved 2 and I need help on the third one. Please see the code.

I can't use a CTE or any other code because it's part of a legacy code and can't be modified except the case on the where clause.

**Requirements**

```
When DepartmentID = 99 then all records
When DepartmentID = 97 then only PriorityID 10 records
All other Departments = all records except PriorityID 10
```

**Sample data**

```
Create table Department
(
    DepartmentID int null,
    PriorityID   int null
)
GO

Insert into Department (DepartmentID, PriorityID) 
values (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 10), (4, 3), (5, 4), 
       (97, 10), (99, 10), (4, 5), (5, 3), (2, 10),
       (99, 2), (97, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 5)
GO

Select * from Department
```

**My query so far**

```
--Declare @intDepartmentID int = 99 OK
--Declare @intDepartmentID int = 97 OK
Declare @intDepartmentID int = 2 -- Need to exclude Record with PriorityID = 10
Declare @intPriorityID int = null

IF @intDepartmentID = 99
Begin
    Set @intDepartmentID = null
    Set @intPriorityID = null
End

If @intDepartmentID = 97
Begin 
    Set @intDepartmentID = null
    Set @intPriorityID = 10
End

Select DepartmentID,
        PriorityID
From Department
Where (DepartmentID = @intDepartmentID or @intDepartmentID is null)
    -- I think I need case statement here?
And (PriorityID = @intPriorityID or @intPriorityID is null)
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Somebody gave you a downvote because you left the requirements in a commented part of the code. I think my answer will do what you like but you might consider editing the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
where DepartmemtID = @DepartmentID and
    <add one of the two case expressions below>

    case @DepartmentID
       when 99 then 1
       when 97 then case when PriorityID = 10 then 1 end
       else case when PriorityID <> 10 then 1 end
    end = 1

-- or

    case 
       when @DepartmentID = 99 then 1
       when @DepartmentID = 97 and PriorityID  = 10 then 1
       when @DepartmentID = 97 then 0 -- all other priorities
       when PriorityID <> 10 then 1
    end = 1
```

The second one is a less nested and, as written, it does rely a bit on the falling through from earlier cases. Also if you have nulls you'll need to tweak for that too.

The general idea is to use `case` to return a matching value (in this example, 1) only for the conditions you're interested in. As these get more complicated it can be nice to be able to condense the logic by relying on earlier cases being false and I think it is also often somewhat easier to maintain. Remember that order matters though.

Comment: Thank you for quick response but is not working for DepartmentID 2
It should show 2 records

Comment: @OdedDror ok, I see you do still want the equality check.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query.

```
SELECT DepartmentID,
        PriorityID
FROM Department
WHERE ((PriorityID != (CASE  
                WHEN (@intDepartmentID NOT IN (97, 99)) THEN 10
                END) AND @intDepartmentID NOT IN (97,99))
OR (PriorityID = (CASE  
WHEN @intDepartmentID = 99 THEN PriorityID
WHEN @intDepartmentID = 97 THEN 10
END) AND @intDepartmentID IN (97,99))
)
--AND (DepartmentID = @intDepartmentID OR @intDepartmentID is null)  --If you want to filter data by department then enable this condition
```

Comment: thank you for quick response but is not working for 99 or 97

Comment: If you provided your desired result for each conditions, that will be good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to have @intPriorityID as one of your parameter since the PriorityID value is determining by the @intDepartmentID.

Please try this and let me know if this is what you need:

```
SELECT DepartmentID,
        PriorityID
FROM Department
WHERE (1 =
    (CASE WHEN @intDepartmentID = 99 THEN 1 END)
    OR
    PriorityID = 
    (CASE WHEN @intDepartmentID = 97 THEN 10 END)
    OR
    PriorityID <> 
    (CASE WHEN @intDepartmentID NOT IN (99,97) THEN 10 END)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You **really** should include in your question what your expected result is for each value of the parameter.

Based on your comments to other answers I think you do want to filter by the `DepartmentID` regardless of the value of the `@intDepartmentID` parameter and use some extra logic to determine whether you want to filter by `PriorityID` as well.

Here is one way to do it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Department AS D
WHERE
    (D.DepartmentID = @intDepartmentID)
    AND
    (
        (@intDepartmentID = 99)
        OR
        (@intDepartmentID = 97 AND D.PriorityID = 10)
        OR
        (@intDepartmentID NOT IN (97, 99) AND D.PriorityID <> 10)
    )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

The simple way how the comparisons are written above assume that `DepartmentID`, `PriorityID` and `@intDepartmentID` can't be `NULL`.
If they **can** be `NULL`, as your `CREATE TABLE` statement in the sample data suggests, then please add few relevant rows with NULLs to the sample data to illustrate all cases in your data. Also, make sure to include expected results to the question.

This kind of query is prone to parameter sniffing problem, that's why I added `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. If you don't, the performance of this query may depend on the value of the parameter that you used to run it for the first time.

Comment: Vladimir,

Thank you for your response, this is what I need how to combine these three togeter

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question:

1) with `@intDepartmentID = 99` you desire all records without filters.
2) with `@intDepartmentID = 97` you desire all records with `PriorityID = 10`
3) with `@intDepartmentID NOT IN  (97, 99)` you desire all records of the specified DepartmentID but with `PriorityID <> 10`

With your test data this mean:

```
DepID   PriID   Visible if:
1       2       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 1
2       2       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 2
3       10      @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 3,  @intDepartmentID = 97
4       3       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 4
5       4       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 5
97      10      @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 97
99      10      @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 97
4       5       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 4
5       3       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 5
2       10      @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 2,  @intDepartmentID = 97
99      2       @intDepartmentID = 99  
97      1       @intDepartmentID = 99  
3       2       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 3
3       3       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 3
2       5       @intDepartmentID = 99,  @intDepartmentID = 2
```

This is the query:

```
Select * 
from Department
where 
    case @intDepartmentID 
        when 99 then 1 
        when 97 then 
            case when (PriorityID = 10) then 1 else 0 end
    else
        case when ((@intDepartmentID = DepartmentID) and (PriorityID <> 10)) then 1 
        else 0 end
    end = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works as expected

```
Where 
( 
    PriorityID = (CASE @intDepartmentID WHEN 99 then PriorityID  WHEN 97 then 10 END )
    OR  (PriorityID != case when @intDepartmentID not in (99,97) then 10 end )
    and (DepartmentID = @intDepartmentID )
)
```